# Select markers clicked a li menu in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, menu, leaflet, marker

I have the following problem:

I created a map with 50 markers and I also created a drop down menu (li menu).

I would like, selecting a voice from the drop down menu, show only a few, for example 3 or 4 markers.

How can I do?

Comment: Please post some code describing what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to create a marker

```
function createIcon(map,lat,lon,message){

var iconBlue= L.icon({
    iconUrl: './icon/marker-icon.png',
    shadowUrl: './icon/marker-shadow.png',

    iconSize: [25,41],
    shadowSize: [41,41],
    iconAnchor:[lat,lon],
    shadowAnchor:[lat,lon],
    popupAnchor:[-25,-10]
});

var marker = L.marker([lat, lon],{icon:iconBlue});      
marker.addTo(map);  
marker.bindPopup(message);
}
```

and this is a li menu

```
<ul id="menu"> 
<li><a href="#">Agrumi</a> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Arance</a>
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Rossa</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Arancione</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Limoni</a>
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Giallo</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Lime</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#">Madarini</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

Selecting "Arance" for example show markers with id "Rossa" and "Arancione"
Selecting "Rossa" only markers with id "Rossa".